# Default belongs_to polymorphic names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphism

If I have a polymorphic `belongs_to`, how should I add a name/attribute for each of the possible associations?

Let's say I have a `Task` which is `taskable` for `user` and `project`, is it possible in a simple way to create the `@task.project` and `@task.user`?

One of them would return the association and the other one `nil`..

Comment: Does your task need to belong to a user and a project at the same time? Or just one or the other?

Comment: It's always one or the other, that's why it's polymorphic..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all - this is bad idea.
You've already chosen polymorphic, why you need something like that?
@project.task / @user.task should be enough.

But as hackish solution something like that will suffice:

```
def comment
  attachable if attachable_type.eql?("Comment")
end
```

Comment: So in my CanCan `ability.rb` I can just say `@task.user.eql?(user)` instead of `@task.taskable.eql?(user)`. The method you provide could just be `def comment; attachable if attachable_type.eql?("Comment"); end`. But I was wondering if there was a simpler solution for when the amount of association types would grow..

Comment: Also, I can find out easy if it's a certain model's child just by `@task.project.present?`, instead of doing `@task.taskable_type.eql?("Project")` all the time.. Which isn't as bad as I thought now that I see it.. Anyway, was just wondering.. :)

Comment: If it's suits you, why not? I never found or know relation which will suit your needs here, so 'take it or leave it' :)

This small method is not too bad anyway, it's 'clean' enough.